# Making a thread inside a class give me error C2664

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

Let me put you in the context. I'm using Qt Creator to make a chat box. I pretty new to C++ so it's kind of a challenge. I want to create a thread using `std::thread`. Here is the code I wrote:

window.h

```
class Window: public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
Window();

public slots:
    void Config();

private:
    void ListenToClients(Server server);

    //member...
};
```

window.cpp

```
Window::Window(): QWidget()
{
    //not important code...    

    do
    {
        //nothing
    }while(config.getLaunch() == false);

    Server myServer(config.getPort(), config.getBroadcast());
    std::thread serverThread(&Window::ListenToClients, this, myServer);

}

void Window::Config()
{
    config.exec();
}

void Window::ListenToClients(Server server)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        server.ListenNewConnections();
    }
}
```

So I get this error: erreur: C2664: `'std::tuple<void (__cdecl Window::* )(Server),Window *,Server>::tuple(std::tuple<void (__cdecl Window::* )(Server),Window *,Server> &&)'ÿ: imossible to convert argument 1 of 'void (__cdecl Window::* )(Server)' in 'std::allocator_arg_t'`

I have no idea why and what it means. I searched a bit but no one seems to have had any error like this one. So, I'm counting on you all.

Answer (score 0):

The "std::allocator_arg_t" sounds like your constructor is involved, since it is allocating something:

`Window::Window(): QWidget()` is not valid, you already inherited from QWidget in your class decleration, so the constructor of QWidget gets called implicitly. `Window::Window()` is sufficient.

Also: i have no idea what `public slots:` should mean. You can completly omit that, since you already have the `public:` qualifier above.

Comment: `public slots` is a Qt extension, the op can't omit it if he wants his `Config()` function to be a slot.

Comment: `Window::Window(): QWidget()` is valid, but calling `QWidget()` with no arguments is not necessary (This is usually done only when passing arguments to `QWidget`'s constructor).